# How to convert a positive number to negative in assembly with limited instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to come up with a way to convert a negative number to a positive but we only have a limited number of instructions we can use and these include: `MOV, Load, XOR, AND, OR, ADD, SUB, LSR(Left Shift), MUL, JMP`. I was unable to come up with something that'll work, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: [Edit] the question to show what you've tried. There are at least 3 different ways using the instructions listed.

Comment: I am surprised that you have not thought of the most obvious one. Do you *have* some idea but could not make it work?

Comment: "How to convert a positive number to negative in assembly with limited instructions?" 
 What negative number do you want it to be?  If any negative number is acceptable, then just move -1 into the register.

Comment: "way to convert a negative number to a positive"  What positive number do you want?  If any positive number is acceptable, then just clear the register.

Comment: Do you know the definition of two’s complement numbers? The conversion follows directly from the definition and uses only the instructions you have available.

Comment: @prl: Even more obvious (and more efficient) to zero another register (e.g. `xor ecx,ecx`) and do `sub ecx, eax` to simply subtract from zero, just like `neg` would within the same register.  2's complement identities are cool and occasionally useful for *conditional* negation or offset by 1, but IDK why people think they're the go-to option for normal negation.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Most people don't consider `0` to be positive.  It's non-negative, but it isn't strictly positive either.  Since mov is allowed, `mov eax,1` is fine if you're trying to rules-lawyer your way out producing an output with the same absolute value as the input :P

Comment: @PeterCordes, the question was seriously underspecified, and, the intention was that if the OP gave it some thought, they might get to the concept of negation.  But there was no response, and so I failed; my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2's compliment negation; you can invert the number then add 1 (e.g. `-(1)` = `(~0x000000001)+1` = `0xFFFFFFFE+1` = `0xFFFFFFFF` = `-1`).

With the instructions you've listed, it might become (NASM syntax, untested):

```
    xor eax,0xFFFFFFFF     ;Invert the number
    add eax,1              ;Add 1
```

Note that this does work, even for the annoying case of `INT_MIN` (e.g. `-(0x80000000)` = `(~0x800000000)+1` = `0x7FFFFFFF+1` = `0x80000000`).

Of course without the restrictions you'd use `neg` (and could've used `not` to invert).